# EditText as Box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

This might look simple and might actually be simple but I need the following screen 
[image]

I completed it using the following xml

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/subject_edt"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
            android:maxLines="5" />
```

everything is fine but the problem is, it is appearing as below on focus

[image]

the cursor should appear on the top left corner, can any one suggest how ti achieve this ??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to set this `android:gravity="top"` **OR** for left you can give `android:gravity="top|left"` property in your `EditText`.

**Refer this.**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/subject_edt"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
            android:maxLines="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:gravity="top"`

```
<EditText
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/subject_edt"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="5" />
```